# авторизация со случайным атрибутом name

Tags: php

нужно в атрибут **name** от логина сделать случайной строкой, но данный пример не авторизируется, пишет ошибку **заполните все поля**, как осущиствить это?

```
 <?php
         $rand = rand(0,50);
        ?>
        <form method="post">
        log<br />
        <input name="login<?=$rand?>" type="text"><br />
        pass<br />
        <input name="password" type="password"><br />
        <input name="log_in" type="submit"><br />
        </form>
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['log_in'])){

        global $connection;
       $login = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["login$rand"]));
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);


            if( empty($login) OR empty($password) ){
                $_SESSION['auth']['errors'] = "заполните все поля";
            }else{


                $password = md5($password);
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$login' AND password = '$password' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
                $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);



                if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1){
                    echo 'Вы авторизировались';

                }else{

                    $_SESSION['auth']['errors'] = 'Логин/пароль введены неверно';
                }

            }

        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная $rand у вас ни где не сохраняется и при отправке формы, когда php файл запускается по новой, то $rand содержит уже другое случайное значение. Отсюда и "заполните все поля".
Сохраняйте $rand в сессию, раз ее все равно используете и при принятии формы на проверку забирайте значение из сессии, а не генерируйте случайное число.

---

Добавил пример

```
<?php
     session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['log_in'])){

        global $connection;
        $rand = $_SESSION['rand'];
        $login = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["login$rand"]));
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);


        if( empty($login) OR empty($password) ){
            $_SESSION['auth']['errors'] = "заполните все поля";
        }else{


            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$login' AND password = '$password' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
            $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);



            if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1){
                echo 'Вы авторизировались';

            }else{

                $_SESSION['auth']['errors'] = 'Логин/пароль введены неверно';
            }

        }

    }

     $rand = rand(0,50);
     $_SESSION['rand'] = $rand;

    ?>
    <form method="post">
    log<br />
    <input name="login<?php echo $rand ?>" type="text"><br />
    pass<br />
    <input name="password" type="password"><br />
    <input name="log_in" type="submit"><br />
    </form>
```

Comment: $_SESSION['rand'] = rand(0,50); $rand = $_SESSION['rand']; и ничего не помогло, может я не так объявил?

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: все работает, большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Что происходит у Вас:

1. Сгенерировали случайное число $rand, например **33**
2. Создали input с названием **login33**
3. Вывели пользователю

Пользователь заполнил поле **login33**, нажал отправить:

1. Сгенерировали опять случайное число $rand, например **17**
2. *опускаем вывод формы*
3. Проверяем пришедшие данные, у нас пришел **login33**, а мы проверяем **login17**. Ошибка, **$_POST["login17"]** не существует.

Используйте сессию:

```
<?php
//...
if (empty($_SESSION['rand'])) {
    $_SESSION['rand'] = rand(0,50);
}
//...
echo '<input name="login'.$_SESSION['rand'].'" type="text"><br />';
//...
$login = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['login'.$_SESSION['rand']]));
//...
```

Comment: $_SESSION['rand'] = rand(0,50);

 $rand =  $_SESSION['rand'];
и ничего не помогло, может я не так объявил?

Comment: Добавил пример. Постоянно генерировать и писать в сессию не нужно. Нужно проверять если там что.

Comment: все равно тот же результат

Comment: Проверяйте что приходит с $_POST и что в $_SESSSION